# CLI vs GUI on a Linux Server in this day and age, what's the downside of GUI?

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, command-line-interface, centos7, graphical-user-interface

I'm starting to look into KVM for virtualization because I can't afford vSphere. I'm "OK" at command line and use it often but no pro. I prefer a GUI, but for a server bare minimum has always been the go to for security and server resources.

1. As of today, has anything changed at all?
2. I want to use CentOS 7 with a GUI, how much more server resources could it possibly use? Still more vulnerabilities? Lets say I have 32gb ram and 8 core cpu.
3. Can I possibly turn off/disable GUI for when I don't need it?

The reason I ask all this is because KVM, I'd much rather see the graphical interface than do everything via command line.

Comment: vSphere isn't necessarily expensive. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Setup an email server, database server, and an NAS/Storage Server, so when it comes time to add hardware, it would be easier to expand (If the information I read before is correct, this is the first step [virtualization]).

Comment: ESXi is free. You're working off of bad information.

Answer (score 2):

1. What?
2. Don't use a full blown DE. All you would need is `virt-manager` and it's dependencies (which are sadly a lot) and X11 forwarding, maybe with some X accelerator (e.g. Xrdp) to make it more bearable over a remote connection. It can even run without any GUI on the server if you connect your local `virt-manager` to the host. This way, you don't need any GUI component on the server.
3. The GUI (`virt-manager`) only runs when you need it. If you have a full X11 session with Xrdp, you can turn it off when you don't need it.
4. As @ewwhite said, vSphere is not necessarily expensive. A single host is even free.